# Apache Cordova: Get keyboard height

Tags: javascript, cordova, keyboard

Is there any way to get the height of the keyboard (of Android and iOS) with Cordova (v2.7) to have the value later on available in the JavaScript on the page/app?

Comment: why don't you upgrade to 3+ that's way old

Comment: I know a simple solution for >=3.2.0

Comment: Hi, could you please share your simple solution for >=3.2.0?